# Application of semigroup method

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, semigroup-of-operators

We consider the following Cauchy problem with certain conditions on the boundary:
$$\eqalign{
  & {u_{tt}}(t,x) + {u_{tt}}(t,0) - {u_{xx}}(t,x) + u(t,L) = 0{\rm{  in ]0}}{\rm{,T[}} \times {\rm{]0}}{\rm{,L[}}  \cr 
  & {\rm{\{ u(0}}{\rm{,x)}}{\rm{,}}{{\rm{u}}_t}(0,x)\}  = \{ f(x),g(x)\}  \cr} $$
My problem is how to transfer the above equation to the Cauchy problem form and how to deal with the term $u(t,L)$ and ${u_{tt}}(t,L)$ :
$$\eqalign{
  & Y' = AY  \cr 
  & Y(0) = {Y_0} \cr} $$
How can I writing this equation under the Cauchy form problem?
Thanks.

Comment: What is a "semogroup", What is a "cobdition ? "Hiw we deal", "On the board" (on the shelf ?) $\to$ "on the boundary", etc. Pay attention to your writing in English (btw English is no more my native language than you)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the boundary conditions are relevant for the matter.

For example, let us assume that the boundary conditions are
$$u(t,0)=0,\qquad u_{tt}(t,L)+u_x(t,L)=-u_t(t,L).$$

If we write $v(t)=u(t,L)$, then the equation can be rewritten as
$$u_{tt}(t,x)=u_{xx}(t,x)-v(t)-v_{tt}(t).$$

But the boundary conditions imply
$$v_{tt}(t)=u_{tt}(t,L)=-u_t(t,L)-u_x(t,L)=-v_t(t)-u_x(t,L)$$
and thus the equation becomes
$$u_{tt}(t,x)=u_{xx}(t,x)-v(t)+v_t(t)+u_x(t,L).$$

Now, if we write

$$Y=\begin{pmatrix}
u\\ 
u_t\\ 
v\\
v_t
\end{pmatrix}$$
then
$$Y'=\begin{pmatrix}
u_t\\ 
u_{tt}\\
v_t\\
v_{tt}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
u_t\\ 
u_{xx}-v+v_t+u_x(L)\\
v_t\\
-v_t-u_x(L)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

So, the problem can be written in the desired form by taking

$$Y=\begin{pmatrix}
u\\ 
\tilde{u}\\ 
v\\
\tilde{v}
\end{pmatrix},\qquad A\begin{pmatrix}
u\\ 
\tilde{u}\\
v\\
\tilde{v}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\tilde{u}\\ 
u_{xx}-v+\tilde{v}+u_x(L)\\
\tilde{v}\\
-\tilde{v}-u_x(L)
\end{pmatrix},\qquad
Y_0=\begin{pmatrix}
f\\ 
g\\ 
f(L)\\
g(L)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Note that, in this setting, the phase space should have the form $H_1\times H_2\times \mathbb C\times\mathbb C$, where $H_1$ and $H_2$ are functional spaces (probably some Sobolev space), and the domain of the operator should include the condition $v=u(L)$.

These considerations are based in a similar problem that I studied and maybe it gives you some insights on how to deal with the boundary terms (but in my case there were no boundary terms in the equation).

---

### Edit (in response to the comments).

Let me consider
$$\eqalign{(1)\qquad   & {u_{tt}} = {u_{txx}} + {u_{xx}}\cr    
(2)\qquad& {u_{tt}}(L) =  - {u_{tx}}(L) - {u_x}(L)  \cr    
(3)\qquad& u(0,t) = {u_t}(0,t) = 0  \cr
(4)\qquad    & u(L,t) = a,{u_t}(L,t) = b  \cr
(5)\qquad    & u(x,0) = v(x),{u_t}(x,0) = w(x) \cr}$$
Multiplying equation $(1)$ by $\overline{u}_t$, integrating over $[0,L]$, performing integration by parts and using the boundary conditions $(2)$-$(4)$ we get
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_0^L\Big(|u_t(x,t)|^2+|u_x(x,t)|^2\Big)dx+|b(t)|^2\right)=-\int_0^L|u_{tx}(x,t)|^2\;dx.$$
So, the energy is given by
\begin{equation}
E(t)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^L\Big(|u_t(x,t)|^2+|u_x(x,t)|^2\Big)dx+\frac{1}{2}|b(t)|^2.
\end{equation}
We consider the phase space
$$H=H_\star^1\times L^2\times\mathbb{C}\quad(\text{where } H_\star^1=\{f\in H^1\mid f(0)=0\})$$
equipped with the norm associated with the energy:
$$\|(u,U,b)\|_H^2=\int_0^\ell\Big(|U|^2+|u_x|^2\Big)dx+|b|^2.$$
Then, the problem can be written as
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{aligned}
&Y'=AY\\
&Y(0)=Y_0
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}
where $Y=(u,U,b)$, $Y_0=(v,w,w(L))$ and $A:D(A)\subset H \to H$ is given by
$$AY=\begin{pmatrix}
U\\ 
U_{xx}+u_{xx}\\ 
U(L)
\end{pmatrix}$$
with domain
$$D(A)=\{Y\in H\mid u\in H^2,\;U\in H_\star^1\cap H^2,\; b=U(L) \}.$$

We have
$$\text{Re }\langle AY,Y\rangle_{H}=-\int_0^L|U|^2\;dx\leq 0$$
and thus $A$ is dissipative.

Here, of course, $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_H$ is the inner product that induces the energy norm $\|\cdot\|_H$:

$$\langle(u^*,U^*,b^*),(u,U,b)\rangle_H=\int_0^L \Big(U^*\overline{U}+u^*_x\overline{u}_x\Big)dx+b^*\overline{b}.$$

Comment: Thanks Pedro, I have solved my problem using the same reasoning,Bu I stuck now in how to show that the operator is dissipative, I read about the B-evolution thory and I don't know how I can apply it.... and can you Sir send me your work about those equations ? thank you.

Comment: @Gustav I'm sorry, but I can't send you the said work. However, you can take a look at [this one](http://www.im.ufrj.br/~rivera/Art_Pub/paperifo.pdf) which is very similar. In fact the ideas used in the well posedness (including the dissipativity) are precisely the same. Unfortunally, I believe it will not be relevant for you because, as I said, there are no boundary terms in the equation and thus the dissipativity is standard (we work with the norm induced by the energy of the system which, in this case, yields a dissipative operator naturally).

Comment: the link that you wrote is not working, and if you can see the follwoing problem, i aplied the same steps that you made but without result,  $$\eqalign{
  & {u_{tt}} = {u_{txx}} + {u_{xx}}  \cr 
  & {u_{tt}}(L) =  - {u_{tx}}(L) - {u_x}(L)  \cr 
  & u(0,t) = {u_t}(0,t) = 0  \cr 
  & u(L,t) = a,{u_t}(0,t) = b  \cr 
  & u(x,0) = v(x),{u_t}(x,0) = w(x) \cr} $$

Comment: @Gustav The link is for [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X1501080X). With respect this problem, see my edit. It seems that these steps yield good results.

Comment: than kyou  brother.....thank you

Comment: Is there any relation between the scalar product in the energy space and the energy functional? I made a lot of research but to no avail.

Comment: @Gustav In the above notation, are you asking if there is any relation between $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_H$ and $E(t)$ (for this particular problem)? If so, we can say that in a sense $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_H$ came from $E(t)$. The expression of $E(t)$ motivates the definition of $H$ and $\|\cdot\|_{H}$. Well, $\|\cdot\|_{H}^2$ is a sum of squares of inner product norms. We define $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_H$ as the sum of the corresponding inner products. Of course, this happens in other problems too. If you are asking for a deeper and general relation, I do not have an answer.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers,, I have a last question: If we don't know the signe of the energy derevative $E'(t)$ we dont't know if it is increasing or decreasing. is there any chance to find a Lyapunov functional wich is equivalent with $E(t)$  decays to 0 ? thank you.

Comment: @Gustav Unfortunately I'm not experienced with Lyapunov functional, so I can't answer your question. I don't know exactly what you need, but if you are having troubles to prove dissipativity in the semigroup setting to get well-posedness (which seems to be the context of the previous discussion) I would suggest Hille-Yosida instead of Lumer-Phillips.

Comment: Thanks Pedro. That's all what i need

Comment: Hello Pedro....Another question, I hope that I do not derenge you, I 'm stuck in how to prove that $A$ is maximal ...$$I - A = f \Leftrightarrow \matrix{
   {u - U = {f_1}}  \cr 
   {U - {U_{xx}} - {u_{xx}} = {f_2}}  \cr 
   {U(L) + {U_x}(L) + {u_x}(L) = {f_3}}  \cr 

 } $$  the first and the second are obvious...How can I prove that with the third...? Thank you a lot Pedro..

Comment: @Gustav Try Method 1 in page 222 of [Brezis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=GAA2XqOIIGoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=brezis+sobolev&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimwtDS5-3TAhULfZAKHQ0ZDOsQ6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=brezis%20sobolev&f=false). In your example it would take the following form.

Comment: Take two (sufficiently regular) functions $\phi$ and $\Phi$ such that $\phi_x(L)=\Phi_x(L)=\Phi(L)=\frac{1}{3}f_3$. Define $g_1=f_1-\phi+\Phi$ and $g_2=f_2-\Phi+\Phi_{xx}+\phi_{xx}$. Show that there are (sufficiently regular) functions $w$ and $W$ satisfying
$$\begin{align}
w - W &= g_1\\
W - W_{xx} - w_{xx} &= g_2\\
W(L)=W_x(L)=w_x(L)&=0
\end{align}$$
Define $u=w+\phi$ and $U=W+\Phi$. Then
$$\begin{align}
u-U=g_1+\phi-\Phi &= f_1\\
U-U_{xx}-u_{xx}=g_2+\Phi-\Phi_{xx}-\phi_{xx} &= f_2\\
U(L) + {U_x}(L) + {u_x}(L)=\tfrac{1}{3}f_3+\tfrac{1}{3}f_3+\tfrac{1}{3}f_3&=f_3
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks Pedro ...thank you sir